# Deploying a wcf web service

Tags: wcf, web-services, publishing

I am new to web services. I have successfully created my WCF web service, now I want to consume it. The client to consume this is on a different machine. I am using Visual Studio 2012. The service that executes a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005.

How do I proceed to make the other party test the service?

Comment: there is something called web/service reference.in the client application just right click on project and click web /service reference ,then add the location of the wcf service.since the client app is a different machine,the url of the server where the wcf service is deployed should be mentioned with  ip address of the server machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to add service reference to the service by right clicking your client application.

Comment: I have a stored procedure for authentication, taking login and password and returning a string . I would like to call the stored procedure(sql server 2005) from my WCF data service ( using entity model and function imports ) and return the output parameter( string ) as the result .

I am using function import to map the stored procedure. How should I proceed ?